# Pivot comma separated values into column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot

I'm trying to easily pivot a series of comma separated values into column headers so I can create a  matrix to capture the relationship between columns and values.

Example:

| Letter | Animals |
| --- | --- |
| A | cow, horse, donkey, goat |
| B | horse, goat |
| C | cow, horse |

I'd like to convert this to a table/matrix like:

| Letter | Cow | Horse | Donkey | Goat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | X | X | X |
| B |  | X |  | X |
| C | X | X |  |  |

I've tried splitting the columns by commas and considered manually writing each unique value as a column header and then writing a formula for each value to determine whether the value is in the column. The issue is that I'm dealing with a huge dataset and this isn't realistic.

Answer (score 2):

Try something along the lines of using with <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A4,
     b,B2:B4,
     c,TOCOL(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(", "&b,", ",SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(b)))),", ",,,1),3),
     d,TOROW(UNIQUE(c)),
     e,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(a),COLUMNS(d),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(COUNTIFS(a,INDEX(a,x),b,"*"&INDEX(d,y)&"*")>=1,"X",""))),
     f,HSTACK(a,e),
     g,HSTACK(A1,d),
     VSTACK(g,f))
```

---

This task can also be accomplished using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>

[image]

---

To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Animals", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Animals"),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Animals", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Trimmed Text", {"Letter"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Letter=text, Animals=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Letter", "Animals", "Index"}, {"Letter", "Animals", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Custom", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Custom"[Animals]), "Animals", "Index", List.Count),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Letter", type text}, {"cow", type text}, {"horse", type text}, {"donkey", type text}, {"goat", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","1","x",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"cow", "horse", "donkey", "goat"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","0",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"cow", "horse", "donkey", "goat"})
in
    #"Replaced Value1"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

This one worked as well on my end, it only assumes we have 4 types of animals:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A4,
     b,UNIQUE(TOROW(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&B2:B4,", ",SEQUENCE(,4)),", "),3),1),
     VSTACK(HSTACK("Letter",b),
     HSTACK(a,IF(COUNTIFS(a,a,B2:B4,"*"&b&"*")>=1,"X",""))))
```

---

Another alternative approach without using <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> instead using of <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&B2:B4,", ",SEQUENCE(,4)),", "),
     b,TOCOL(IF(ISNA(a),NA(),A2:A4),3),ub,UNIQUE(b),
     c,TOCOL(a,3),uc,TOROW(UNIQUE(c)),
     e,MMULT(--(TOROW(b)=ub),--(c=uc)),
     HSTACK(VSTACK("Letter",ub),VSTACK(uc,IF(e>0,"X",""))))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

### Pivot Delimited Column

[image]

```
=LET(table,A1:B11,rlCol,1,clCol,2,clDlm,", ",
        Yes,"X",No,"",FirstHeader,"",
    GetTableData,LAMBDA(table,
        LET(d,DROP(table,1),IF(d="","",d))),
    GetUniqueDelimitedRow,LAMBDA(ColData,dlm,
        UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(ColData&dlm),dlm,,1,1),1)),
    fh,IF(FirstHeader="",INDEX(table,1,1),FirstHeader),
    td,GetTableData(table),
    rlc,INDEX(td,,rlCol),rl,UNIQUE(FILTER(rlc,rlc<>"")),
    clc,INDEX(td,,clCol),cl,GetUniqueDelimitedRow(clc,clDlm),
    vc,REDUCE(cl,rl,LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        frl,GetUniqueDelimitedRow(FILTER(clc,rlc=r),clDlm),
        v,IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(cl,frl)),Yes,No),
    VSTACK(rr,v)))),
HSTACK(VSTACK(fh,rl),vc))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(s,", ",u,UNIQUE(TOROW(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(s&B2:B4,s,SEQUENCE(,99)),s),3),1),VSTACK(HSTACK(A1,u),HSTACK(A2:A4,REPT("X",ISNUMBER(SEARCH(s&u&s,s&B2:B4&s))))))
```